# Recuperar mediante un Get de una pagina redireccionada

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Hola soy nueva y necesito ayuda, necesito mediante un onclick redireccionar a una pagina y recuperar mediante javascript los datos en un formulario para que así sean editados y guardados, pero no logro  recuperar lo datos luego de redireccionar , si alguien me puede ayudar. Gracias d antemano.

```
function Create_Work_Order(id) {
    window.location.href = "https://localhost:44352/Reports/CreateWorOrder"

    $.get("../Reports/Create_Work_Order/?id=" + id, function (data) {
        document.getElementById('w_name').value = data[0].company_name;
        document.getElementById('w_contact').value = data[0].customer_name;
        document.getElementById('w_phone').value = data[0].phone_number;
        document.getElementById('w_country').value = data[0].country;
        document.getElementById('w_location').value = data[0].Location_ServicedProvided;
        document.getElementById('w_inspect').value = data[0].Cost_Inspector;
        document.getElementById('w_supervisor').value = data[0].Cost_Inspector;
        document.getElementById('w_cost').value = data[0].Other_Cost;
        document.getElementById('w_required').value = data[0].Personal_Required;
        document.getElementById('w_tool').value = data[0].Tool;

    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer quieres hacer dos cosas, y este codigo tendria que estar en dos paginas diferentes.
Si tu boton te enviara primero al formulario, puedes hacer un simple hyperlink

```
<a href="https://localhost:44352/Reports/CreateWorOrder">Ir al formulario</a>
```

Y despues en la pagina CreateWorkOrder, tienes que cachar el evento onSubmit y trabajar con el formulario.

Answer (score 0):

En la primer línea de tu función te estás yendo de la página en la que actualmente estás.